# How to access instance variable inside @classmethod?

Tags: python

I have two class as below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


class B(A):      
    @classmethod
    def good(cls):
        return cls.a

a = B('good')
```

When I run `print(a.good())`
It shows `AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'a'`

How to access `a` variable from `good` method?

Comment: You can't, that's *the whole point of a classmethod*, instead of having access to the instance, it has access to the class

Comment: Which instance do you want to access from that method? If it's the one you called the method on (like in your example), just make it a regular method.

Comment: If you defined `A.a` then classmethods of subclasses will be able to access `cls.a`, as the lookup of the attribute only applies at the class level - hence `classmethod`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In no way.

`@classmethod`s do not have access to instances of the class.